# downloading camera snapshot via http url in python

Tags: python, http, web

I have NVR from Dahua, and I have access to admin user on this device.
Using this account I'm trying to get snapshots from IP cameras, connected to this NVR.
According to dahua documentation, to do this, I can use this url link
http://Username:Password@IP-Address/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=1

When i replace "username" etc with correct data, it works
I can paste this link in my web browser, and it displays snapshot from chosen camera.

Now I want to do the same in the python code, because those snapshots will be analised by neural network so I need them as python variable not as a picture in my browser.

I wrote some simple code, which looks like this

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO


url = "http://username:password@ip_address/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=10"


response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    image.show()
else:
    print(f" failed to download the image, respond from website: {response.status_code}")
```

Obviously I used actual username, not "username".
And I got error  HTTP: 401, which means Unauthorized connection. Which is weird, because if I take this exact url, and copy it from my code to web browser, there is no problem with authorization. Eveything works

I supose that this might be some sort of firewall blockade, or other security stuff happening in NVR configuration, that prevents me from connecting via python code.

I also tried another authentication method, but got the same HTTP 401 respond

```
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = ('username', 'password')


url = "http://ip_address/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=10"


response = session.get(url)
```

I honestly don't know. I am Data Scientist, not web developer, nor cybersecurity expert, so my knowledge in these areas is very limited

Comment: Is the device where you're trying your script from, also connected to the same network as your NVR?

Comment: yes, I am in the same network, and I can log to this device via web browser. I also triple checked this url in browser and it 100% works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made it work.
First of all, I added some code to get more informations about the error

```
import requests
import logging
import http.client as http_client

http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
```

I found information that server requires Digest authorization method

Then, I pasted the link in my web browser , and pressed F12 to look what is happening. In the logs, I also found that there is Digest authorization method being used.

Then I checked request documentation, and simple "get" function is using Basic authorization which is being denied by the server.

Now it was very simple to fix it, all I did is just replaced

```
url = "http://username:password@ip_address/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=10"
response = requests.get(url)
```

with

```
url = "http://ip_address/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=10"
auth = HTTPDigestAuth('username', 'password')

response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
```

And it works like a charm :)